# Am trying to create a folder with random digits, and put a file inside of it

Tags: php, copy, mkdir

Here is my code

```
$file = 'post.php';
$root = '/' . $dir_auth1 . '/'. $file;
$folder = mkdir(rand(10,10000)); 
$folder5 = $folder . '/' . $file;
echo $folder5;
if($folder) {

if (!copy($root, $folder5)) {
        echo "failed to copy $file...\n";

} else {
    echo "<p style='font-size:35px;font-family:verdana;text-align:center;'>status was successfuly created.</p>";
}


}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is upon a form submit create a directory with random digits and place the $file variable inside of the randomized directory

Comment: any error in code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create random folders using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290391/create-random-folders-using-php)

Comment: @Dhaval Dave
It compiles right but its functionality isnt working.

Comment: Yes, using uniqid() did help, however when I submit the form with the php, and even when I echo it this still returns 1

Answer (score 0):

mkdir - return bool. Please [read about mkdir](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mkdir.php)

And rewrite you code something like this:

```
$file = 'post.php';
$root = '/' . $dir_auth1 . '/'. $file;
$folder = rand(10,10000);
mkdir($folder); 
$folder5 = $folder . '/' . $file;
```

And check you **if**. You always **true**. (not empty string = true)

Comment: thank you
So I want the created directory with random digits to have the file stuffed inside of it, not have it return 1.

Comment: mkdir($dir);  at that line of code what is the $dir, variable? 
What are you referring to? Its not in mine.

Comment: It won't copy because it is still returning one, when the page loads. I have it echo $folder and $folder5. Still says 1.