# How to create a temporary directory in PHP without risking races?

Tags: php, python

I was wondering if PHP had something similar to Python's tempdir.mkdtemp(). PHP's System::mktemp seems to be unsuitable if [that code](https://github.com/pear/pear-core/blob/master/System.php#L435) is still used for it. I guess I could implement the same functionality as provided in Python myself, but I can hardly belief that I'm the only one who has seeked for that functionality and would like to avoid reinventing the wheel.

The code should be operating system agnostic, therefore using exec as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17280327/1078224 is not an option.

Comment: [mkdir()](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) is os  agnostic

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Where are you worried about this being an issue? You could probably mitigate risk by using randomly-named directories of sufficient length.

Comment: i would not use 'random' when php has uniqid()

Comment: @matcarlson: Well, surely one can try to create a randomly named directory, check if it succeeded and retry else. That's basically what Python is doing. For why I'm doing this: There is no security risk involved, but I still would my code not to fail in the unlikely case that another program created a directory with the same name as the one I attempted to create.

Comment: create a directory just for the directories this function or class will make?

Comment: @Nazca: In practice, this will most likely lead to no conflicts occuring. In theory, that doesn't prevent anyone (user or different process) from creating folders/files in this folder.

Comment: are you trying to prevent users from making folders and files in your directory or are you trying to make directories without conflicts?

Comment: I'm (or rather was) trying to do the latter.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
if is_dir("myNewDir"){
    //rename the directory your trying to make and do it again
}else{
    mkdir("myNewDir); 
}
?>
```

https://www.php.net/is_dir

I'm not sure this is exactly as hard as making a wheel.

EDIT:

```
<?php
$dirName = substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 8);
while (@mkdir($dirName) === false){
    $dirName = substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 0);
}
echo "Created directory: " . $dirName ;
?>
```

This should result in no race.

Comment: Why do you think that there is no race between calling is_dir and mkdir?

Comment: I guess thats a little harder than a wheel.

Comment: You would have to add some code to change the directory name of either the conflict or your new directory but I believe this is what your looking for.