# Post Form data not received by backend

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to see form data using $_Post in backend for the named inputs but nothing (tried many different solutions)

I've put code below of the FE page to review but as far as i can see it should work.

```html
<div class="wrap">
        <h1>
                Course Lesson Settings
        </h1>
        <p>
                Use this interface to create/update course lessons.
        </p>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @php
                wp_nonce_field('course_modules_settings_action', 'course_modules_settings_nounce');
                @endphp

                <table class="form-table" role="presentation">
                        <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">Create or update a course lesson</th>
                                        <td>
                                                <p>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Upload Lesson" />
                                                        <select name="module-value">
                                                                <option value="" selected>Create a lesson</option>
                                                                @if (App::isArrayWithValue($posts))
                                                                        @foreach($posts as $singlePost)
                                                                                <option value="{{ $singlePost->ID }}">
                                                                                        {!! $singlePost->post_title !!}
                                                                                </option>
                                                                        @endforeach
                                                                @endif
                                                        </select>
                                                </p>
                                        <td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">Lesson archive</th>
                                        <td>
                                                <p>
                                                        <input type="file" name="module" required/>
                                                </p>
                                                <p>
                                                        Select the <code>zip</code> containing the course.
                                                </p>
                                        <td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                        <th scope="row"></th>
                                        <td>
                                                <p>
                                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Upload Lesson">
                                                </p>
                                        <td>
                                </tr>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
        </form>
</div>
```

To see the variable in the backend

Here is the backend code which calls the view - then processes the form - Dont know the ins and outs of this project as im taking over for another person:

```php
<?php

namespace App\CourseModule;

class CourseModuleSettings {
    public function init() {
        add_action('init', [$this, 'createPostType']);
        add_action('admin_menu', [$this, 'addAdminMenu']);
    }

    public function createPostType() {
        register_post_type('course-modules', [
            'label' => 'Course Lessons',
            'labels' => [
                'name' => 'Course Lessons',
                'singular_name' => 'Course Lesson',
            ],
            'supports' => ['title'],
            'taxonomies' => ['year_level', 'curriculum', 'topic'],
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'public' => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'menu_position' => 25,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-media-archive',
            'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'can_export' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => false,
            'capability_type' => 'page',
            'searchable' => false,
        ]);
    }

    public function addAdminMenu() {
        add_menu_page(
            'Course Lessons Settings',
            'Course Lessons Settings',
            'manage_options',
            'course-modules-settings',
            [$this, 'adminPageContent'],
            'dashicons-schedule',
            200
        );
    }

    public function adminPageContent() {
        $this->handleAdminPageActions();

        $posts = get_posts([
            'post_type' => 'course-modules',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'any',
        ]);

        echo \App\template('admin.page-course_module_settings', [
            'posts' => $posts
        ]);
    }

    public function handleAdminPageActions() {
        if (
            (isset($_POST['action']) ||
                isset($_POST['course_modules_settings_nounce'])) &&
            (!wp_verify_nonce(
                $_POST['course_modules_settings_nounce'],
                'course_modules_settings_action'
            ) ||
                !check_admin_referer(
                    'course_modules_settings_action',
                    'course_modules_settings_nounce'
                ))
        ) {
            $this->displayNotice('Invalid nounce', 'error');
            return;
        }

         if ($_POST['action'] === 'Upload Lesson') {
            if (
                isset($_POST['module-value']) && 
                !empty($_FILES)
            ) {
                // Check if the file is uploaded
                $file = $_FILES['module'];
                if (
                    !file_exists($file['tmp_name']) || 
                    !is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'])
                ) {
                    $this->displayNotice("Couldn't find the uploaded file.", 'error');
                    return;
                }

                // Validate the file
                $archiveFolder = $this->validateUploadedFile($file);
                if (!$archiveFolder) {
                    $this->displayNotice("Invalid uploaded file.", 'error');
                    return;
                }

                // Get the upload folder
                $uploadFolder = $this->checkOrCreateModuleFolder();
                if (!$uploadFolder) {
                    $this->displayNotice("Couldn't create upload folder", 'error');
                    die();
                }

                
                $hashFolder = null;
                
                if (empty($_POST['module-value'])) {
                    // Create a new module
                    $hashFolder = $this->createModuleHash($uploadFolder, $file["name"]);
                    
                } else {
                    // Update module
                    $hashFolder = \get_field('module_hash', $_POST['module-value']);
                }

                // Create or update the post
                $postId = wp_insert_post([
                    'ID' => $_POST['module-value'],
                    'post_title' => $file["name"],
                    'post_type' => 'course-modules',
                ]);
                // Update the ACF fields
                \update_field('module_hash', $hashFolder, $postId);
                \update_field('module_url', "/wp-content/uploads/course-modules/{$hashFolder}/index.html", $postId);

                $moduleFolder = sprintf('%s%s%s', $uploadFolder, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $hashFolder);
                
                // Move the file to the upload folder
                $this->rcopy($archiveFolder, $moduleFolder);

                $this->displayNotice("Lesson uploaded. <a href=\"/wp-admin/post.php?post={$postId}&action=edit\">Edit lesson</a>", 'success');
            } else {
                $this->displayNotice("Please make sure you've uploaded a file.", 'error');
                return;
            }
        // }
    }

    protected function createModuleHash($uploadFolder, $fileName) {
        // Create the long hash for the module folder
        $attempts = 0;
        $maxAttempts = 1000;
        $hashFolder = null;
        do {
            $hashFolder = hash('sha256', "$attempts" . $fileName);
            $moduleFolder = sprintf('%s%s%s', $uploadFolder, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $hashFolder);
        } while (
            !mkdir($moduleFolder, 0700) &&
            $attempts++ < $maxAttempts
        );
        return $hashFolder;
    }

    protected function checkOrCreateModuleFolder() {
        $wpUploadFolder = wp_upload_dir();
        if (isset($wpUploadFolder['basedir'])) {
            // Check if the modules folder exists
            $path = sprintf('%s%s%s', $wpUploadFolder['basedir'], DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'course-modules');
            if(
                !file_exists($path)
            ) {
                // Create the folder
                mkdir($path, 0700);
                // Add basic index.php to prevent default listing of the folder
                file_put_contents(sprintf('%s%s%s', $path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'index.php'), '');
            }

            return $path;
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected function validateUploadedFile($file) {
        // Check the extension
        $name = basename($file["name"]);
        $fileMetadata = pathinfo($name);
        if ($fileMetadata['extension'] === 'zip') {
            // Create tmp directory
            $tmpDir = $this->createTmpDir();
            if (!$tmpDir) {
                $this->displayNotice("Couldn't create temporary directory.", 'error');
                return false;
            }
            $newTmpLocation = sprintf('%s%s%s', $tmpDir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $file['name']);
            // Move the uploaded file
            move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $newTmpLocation);
            // Extract the archive and validate the files in it
            // $zipFile = new \PhpZip\ZipFile();
            $zip = new ZipExtract();
            $res = $zip->open($newTmpLocation);
            if ($res === true) {
                
                // Extract the archive in the tmp folder
    
                $folders = [
                    'assets',
                    'lib',
                    'content'
                ];
                $files = [
                    'index.html',
                    'goodbye.html',
                ];
                foreach ($folders as $folder) {
                    $extractionErrors = $zip->extractSubdirTo(
                        $tmpDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folder, 
                        $folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
                    );

                    if (count($extractionErrors)) {
                        echo "<pre>";
                        var_dump($extractionErrors);
                        echo "</pre>";
                        $this->displayNotice("Couldn't extract archive", 'error');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    $extractionErrors = $zip->extractTo(
                        $tmpDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 
                        $file,
                    );
                }
                
                
                $zip->close();

                // Check if the base files and folder for the module exist
                if (
                    $this->testFolderStructure($tmpDir)
                ) {
                    $tmpDir = sprintf('%s%s%s', $tmpDir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'content');

                    if (
                        $this->testFolderStructure($tmpDir)
                    ) {
                        $this->displayNotice("Invalid content in extracted lesson archive. Expects: index.html, goodbye.html, lib, assets.", 'error');
                        echo "<pre>";
                        var_dump([
                            file_exists(sprintf('%s%s%s', $tmpDir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'index.html')) ,
                            file_exists(sprintf('%s%s%s', $tmpDir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'goodbye.html')) ,
                            file_exists(sprintf('%s%s%s', $tmpDir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'lib')),
                            file_exists(sprintf('%s%s%s', $tmpDir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'assets')),
                            sprintf('%s%s%s', $tmpDir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'assets')
                        ]);
                        echo "</pre>";
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                // Remove the archive
                unlink($newTmpLocation);

                return $tmpDir;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function testFolderStructure($directory) {
        return (
            !file_exists(sprintf('%s%s%s', $directory, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'index.html')) ||
            !file_exists(sprintf('%s%s%s', $directory, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'goodbye.html')) ||
            !file_exists(sprintf('%s%s%s', $directory, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'lib')) ||
            !file_exists(sprintf('%s%s%s', $directory, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'assets'))
        );
    }

    /**
     * Code from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707801/making-a-temporary-dir-for-unpacking-a-zipfile-into
     */
    protected function createTmpDir($dir = null, $prefix = 'tmp_', $mode = 0700, $maxAttempts = 1000) {
        /* Use the system temp dir by default. */
        if (is_null($dir)) {
            $dir = sys_get_temp_dir();
        }

        /* Trim trailing slashes from $dir. */
        $dir = rtrim($dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

        /* If we don't have permission to create a directory, fail, otherwise we will
        * be stuck in an endless loop.
        */
        if (!is_dir($dir) || !is_writable($dir)) {
            return false;
        }

        /* Make sure characters in prefix are safe. */
        if (strpbrk($prefix, '\\/:*?"<>|') !== false) {
            return false;
        }

        /* Attempt to create a random directory until it works. Abort if we reach
        * $maxAttempts. Something screwy could be happening with the filesystem
        * and our loop could otherwise become endless.
        */
        $attempts = 0;
        do {
            $path = sprintf('%s%s%s%s', $dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $prefix, mt_rand(100000, mt_getrandmax()));
        } while (
            !mkdir($path, $mode) &&
            $attempts++ < $maxAttempts
        );

        return $path;
    }

    /**
     * Code from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835492/move-all-files-and-folders-in-a-folder-to-another
     */
    // Function to remove folders and files 
    protected function rrmdir($dir) {
        if (is_dir($dir)) {
            $files = scandir($dir);
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                    $this->rrmdir("$dir/$file");
                }
            }
            rmdir($dir);
        }
        else if (file_exists($dir)) unlink($dir);
    }

    /**
     * Code from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835492/move-all-files-and-folders-in-a-folder-to-another
     */
    // Function to Copy folders and files      
    protected function rcopy($src, $dst) {
        if (file_exists ( $dst )) {
            $this->rrmdir ( $dst );
        }
        if (is_dir ( $src )) {
            mkdir ( $dst );
            $files = scandir ( $src );
            foreach ( $files as $file ) {
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                    $this->rcopy( "$src/$file", "$dst/$file" );
                }
            }
        } else if (file_exists ( $src )) {
            copy ( $src, $dst );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display an admin notice
     *
     * @param  string $content the content of the notice
     * @param  string $type (Optional) the type of notice
     * @return void
     */
    protected function displayNotice($content, $type = 'info') {
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-<?= $type ?> is-dismissible">
            <p><?= str_replace("\r\n", '<br/>', $content) ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}

(new CourseModuleSettings())->init();
```

Comment: Is that a typo in the second parameter of the call to `wp_nonce_field()`? I don't know Wordpress, so I'm not sure if it matters that it says `nounce` at the end. What do you get in `$_POST` when you display it for debugging?

Comment: Do you have the form processing code in the same file as the form code? As there's no `action` parameter in your `<form>` tag that would be what I'd presume.

Comment: Tried to give more context in answer 1 - thanks for your help - @droopsnoot i dont think so but ill look into it

Comment: @droopsnoot - na it looks like thats legit

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.